# Format a string of numbers with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to take a number such as:
59.234 and make it 00:59.234
and
1:01.555 01:01.555

I need to perform this on a column in a csv file.

Comment: Are you converting time values? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @mklement0 - it looks like `mm:ss.fff` to me. i can't think of a graceful way to get that into a time unit, so i would likely chop it up, pad it, and then mash it back into one thing. graceless ... but that otta work. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks!  Theo's answer did the trick! It was just what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input csv file looks anything like this:

```
"Something","Time","MoreStuff"
"whatever","59.234","whereever"
"etcetera","1:01.555","and so forth"
```

you can use below code to format the time values as you need them:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\thefile.csv'
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    # get the field to format. in this demo it is $_.Time
    $whole, $fraction = ($_.Time -replace '[:,]').PadLeft(8, '0') -split '\.'
    # overwrite the field with the formatted time string
    $_.Time = '{0}:{1}.{2}' -f $whole.Substring(0,2), $whole.Substring(2,2), $fraction.PadRight(3, '0')
}

# output on screen
$csv

# write to new file
$csv | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\theNewfile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
Something Time      MoreStuff   
--------- ----      ---------   
whatever  00:59.234 whereever   
etcetera  01:01.555 and so forth
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be graceful but it might work depending on how the format looks like if you have a smaller or larger number. Eg. 1:59.234 or just 23.

```
$CSV | select-object @{ Name = "MyTimeSpan"; Expression = { [System.TimeSpan]::Parse(("00:00:" + $_.ColumnName).Substring(("00:00:" + $_.ColumnName).Length - 12,12)) }}
```